# How could a musician get continent famous without radio or instant communication?

Tags: post-apocalypse, music

In the 26th century, 500 years after a nuclear apocalypse, most modern technological marvels, like radio, television and telephone have been wiped out. Which means, if you want to find out what’s going on out in the opposite side of the country, you have to go there yourself. So, back to the point. In the small town of Des, Iowa, a child was born, named Reffrey Beatus Apparatus.

He was an orphan, and was taken in by the humanitarian organization, O.R.E. There he took up the musical arts, and his skills were unmatched by any other. He left Des, and wanted to make a name for himself in the wide wastes. So, he wants to become a star, but, given the lack of instant communication, what would be the best path for our young musician to make?

Comment: If a popstar sings in a desert and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: @L.Dutch: The pop star is their hearing it

Comment: What infrastructure is there?  Do people listen to music in great auditoriums?  Do they listen to chamber music?  Are artists who play for high ranking people given name recognition?  How did artists gain such recognition before the 20th century?  Can Reffery do what they did?

Comment: The same way folks got famous before radio and television...by publicity stunts in the newspapers. Example: [P.T. Barnum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._T._Barnum).

Comment: @Cort Ammon: They have music clubs, and larger concert halls are reserved for more popular music men

Comment: By the way, Mozart, Bach & C. did very well just counting on horse based data transmission protocol

Comment: @L.Dutch: I looked it up, but it didn’t give me the details in enough clearness

Comment: If your society has enough population, spare time, and wealth for music clubs and concert halls, then they can re-invent railways, telegraphs, etc. Many stars make their name exploiting new media....

Comment: @user535733: They are back at late 1600s to early 1700s technology.

Comment: I think the biographies and articles on Mozart, Bach and Beethoven cover this topic pretty well.

Comment: Aristotle was famous up until know, and he did not even know that internet will exist, this guy will be famous also, just put him in the books.

Comment: @L.Dutch has a point that needs underscoring.  Bach, Mozart, and all the classical masters needed only two things to become famous world-wide without radio or instantaneous comm.: the printing press and time.  (And, of course, their inexhaustible talent, but that's a given in your question.)

Comment: Before instant communication, it usually took the patronage of a king or a rich person renowned for their patronage of fine arts, who took this artist around to places and showed them off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Mameluke empire there are scholarly records of philosophers and educators lamenting that stringed instrument players and singers are more critically acclaimed than great physicians and mathematicians. These early pop-stars seemed to derive their fame much the same way our "famous for being famous" types do today. Mass exposure and marketing and associating with the rich and powerful. They just used different methods to do so. They traveled a lot and hired criers to announce their arrivals, which were usually accompanied by extravagant displays of wealth and spectacle. Think Alladdin's initial appearance to jasmine while masquerading as a prince. Everywhere you go you hire troupes of dancers, animal handlers to parade rare and exotic beasts, slaves or servants to sing praises toss out handfuls of coins or loaves of bread and generally add to the jovial atmosphere, fire-breathers, jugglers, bare chested women etc etc. If nobody knew who you were before they do now, and if you have the musical or choreographic talent you then make a big deal out of presenting yourself and your services to the local strong-man. After such a blatant display of wealth and pomp he basically has no choice but to respond in kind, a big festival is held, lots of wine is drank, lots of babies get made, lots of coin flies around. His people get distracted from their crushing poverty for a while, their leader reaffirms his power and benevolence, and you get a bit more famous. He presents you with lavish gifts and you depart. Rinse and repeat.

That's not to say it's foolproof. History is rife with tales of famous entertainers whose careers met nasty ends because they caught the local despot at a bad time or somehow offended him, or perhaps served one of his adversaries and ended up on his bad side. Or maybe he became jealous and wanted you all to himself. Or maybe just couldn't afford to pay you so decided to accuse you of something and have you punished. Or maybe hes just a bit inbred and a lot mad and just likes seeing guitar players tossed off of buildings.

Its a lot more dangerous than modern day celebrity-hood, but before electronic recordings and telecommunications there were indeed singers and dancers famed across entire empires. They just had to travel a lot and have enough money and connections to promote themselves a lot. Basically you use your talent to get noticed by a wealthy patron, hopefully getting onto his permanent court of sycophants. He will use you to show off to other visiting dignitaries. After a few years he dies, grows bored, or just lets you go. You now use those connections to travel and patronize the courts of the high and mighty. Eventually you become wealthy and widely recognized enough that you can become your own promoter and travel as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Consider expressing Reffrey's musical gifts through composition rather than performance.  Paper sheets full of musical notation are a lot easier to spread around a post-mass-communication world than the actual performer.

Check out the DragonSinger Trilogy portion of [Anne McCaffrey's DragonRiders series](http://pernhome.com/aim/) for a spectacular handling of music's role in a low-tech world.  From Teaching to Reporting to Entertaining and much, much more, the Harper's of Pern are a powerful part of that world.  And most of the famous members of that guild, were composers.

Answer (score 1):

[Phonograph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph)

> as demand for certain records grew, popular artists still needed to re-record and re-re-record their songs. Reportedly, the medium's first major African-American star George Washington Johnson was obliged to perform his "The Laughing Song" (or the separate "Laughing Coon") literally thousands of times in a studio during his recording career. Sometimes he would sing "The Laughing Song" more than fifty times in a day, at twenty cents per rendition. (The average price of a single cylinder in the mid-1890s was about fifty cents.)